# ELF .so file, can I run it in some way on my windows thorugh java?

Tags: java, android, native, elf, shared-libraries

I have tree .so files, one for x86 and two other processors.

I can use them on my android simulator to call functions from the .so file:

```
  static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("nameoflib");
  }

  public native long myNativeFunction();
```

Can I modify these files in any way so that I can use them in java on my windows computer?

(I mean, in SOME way it must be possible, since I can run them on my windows in the android simulator.

(The reason is I need a random function from the library that I dont know how it works.)

Answer (score 0):

.so files are dynamically linked libraries in linux/unix, like .dll files in windows.
You can use these .so files in the simulator of the device, because it is the emulator of android (linux system).

You need to have the source code to get the dll for windows.